Jetpack Compose TextInput "template" aware, able to color templates like {{variable}} in a different color
I need a component just like the Postman URL editor.
The component needs to be able to support templates and color them distinctly as well as offer the value with a tooltip:
Here's some code:
TextField(
            value = urlText,
            onValueChange = {
                urlText=it
            },
            colors = textSelectionColors
        )

Url with template example:
{{base_url}}/{{sub-path}}test/ids/{{oneid}}

I have tried extending the BasicTextField component with decoration box but editing starting to be very random and buggy.

Have you tried AnnotatedString?
